# Text not being transformed to the right position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a json data with translate position within it, and I return that data along with a centroid with the function I have created. When I run this code, the text runs in a straight line along the bottom:

```
var prac = svg.append("g.prac")
            .data(inner)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d,i){return "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")" + d.trans;});   

        prac.append("text")
            .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")
           .text(function(d) {return d.text;})
        ;
```

I have also tried to append (svg:text) instead of grouping it, but it just doesnt appear.

Can anyone help me with my problem? ... I have attached an example to make my problem more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/48/

Comment: Don't have enough time to get you all the way there, but I think the key problem is that those `g` elements aren't actually being appended to your `g.prac` element - speaking of which, `svg.append("g.prac")` appends a `<g.prac>` instead of a `<g class='prac'>`.

Comment: Yeah - just checked, and they're being appended to the bottom of the page (after `</body>`, even). That's likely why that text is showing up where it is. If you aren't already using it, the Google Chrome Developer Tools makes working in `d3` MUCH easier - the "Elements" tab really helps for tracking down elements that aren't being appended where you think they should be. Highly recommended.

Comment: @MattParker thanks for the tip! But, how can I prevent it from being appended to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you're appending `<g.prac>` elements instead of `<g class='prac'>` elements. To fix that, switch code that looks like this:

```
svg.append("g.prac")
```

with this:

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "prac")
```

Second, and more critically, you need to select the elements to which you want to bind your data - **even if they haven't been created yet** (Scott Murray has [a nice explanation of this](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data/)). So your `prac` should be made like this:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "prac")
  .selectAll("g")
    .data(inner)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr(...)
```

Here's a jsfiddle where I've made that conversion for both `g.prac` and `g.presence`: http://jsfiddle.net/c6w7j/4/

I think that gets you part of the way there. I'm not sure that that text is actually landing where you want it, but this should at least fix your structure.

Comment: No it's fine I'll position them where I want. Just a quick lil question, you see with the var presence. I have repeating text from the json data (USA,USA etc), is the a way to filter it out so it only repeats the text once - even if there's more than one.

Comment: Getting unique values can be a pain in the ass. Try something like `var countries = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.Country; }).entries(nodes);`  It can take work to get the output structure right, but some combination of [`nest`, `key`, `rollup`, `map`, and `entries`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest) should get you there.